# Saving a one to many relationship into a database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need some help saving data into my database using a one to many relationship (one bear many fish). Would be great if you could show me some example on how to do it. Because I can't seem to get the data because my bear_id is 0. (eg: bear_id = 1 can retrieve fish_id of 1 and 2)

Here are my codes:

for blade.php:

```
{{Form::text('name_of_bear, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}} --> first page, once user has entered bear name it will redirect it to the fish page to enter the checkbox


<input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Salmon"> Salmon <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="type_of_fish[]" value="Sardine"> Sardine --> second page after user has entered the data for bear they will click next and be redirected to here
```

for my tables:

```
Schema::create('bears, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
            $table->string(name); 
            $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create(fishs, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
            $table->string(name); 
            $table->integer(bear_id);
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Fish model:

```
class fish extends Eloquent
{
        protected $fillable = array('name', 'bear_id');

    // DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS 
    public function bears() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\bear);
    }
}
```

bear model:

```
class bear extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public function fishs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\fish,'bear_id');
    }
}
```

For the controller part, I am still learning so I don't really know how to use it

Controller:

```
public function view(Request $request)
{
        $fish= new fish();

        $fishType= $request->input('type_of_fish');
        $fish->type_of_fish= json_encode($fishType);

         $fish->save();

$bear= new bear();
        $bear->Name = $request->input('name_of_bear');
$bear->save();
$fish->bear_id = $bear->id;    
$fish->save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than manually setting the bear_id of the fish model, Eloquent provides a way for you to [associate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) the models. Note that I'm using the static create() method instead of instantiating new models and filling in the properties separately.

```
$fish = fish::create(['type_of_fish' => json_encode($fishType)]);
$bear = bear::create(['Name' => $request->input('name_of_bear');

$fish->bears()->associate($bear);
$fish->save();
```

However, since you're not dealing with existing resources at this point, you can use the Eloquent's [create](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method for relationships.

```
$bear = Bear::create(['Name' => $request->input('name_of_bear')]);
$bear->fishes()->create(['type_of_fish' => $fishType);
```

This will create a new fish and then auto associate it with the bear created in the line above.

Comment: Is it possible to separate the create function in a separate controller and do an associate instead? Because I am creating a form with 2 pages which take user input and I don't know what to do inside the controller